# Get user info Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am new to laravel, I have controller to get user related posts,I have Passport configured, I need to get current user id and name.
Can you help me plz?

Comment: Please post your code that you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 
`$user = auth()->guard('api')->user();`

Then you can get user name or id like this :

`$user->id;`

`$user->name;`